# C++ Program crash when doing string assign

Tags: c++, string, class

I have a weird problem, this is my code :

**test.h**

```
#ifndef _test_
#define _test_
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class Test {
public:
    Test();
    ~Test();
    void addName(std::string _Name);
private:
    std::string Name;
};
#endif // _test_
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"
Test::Test() {}
Test::~Test() {}
void Test::addName(std::string _Name) {
    std::cout << _Name << std::endl;
    Name = _Name;
    std::cout << _Name << std::endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Test* project;
    project->addName("abc");
    return 0;
}
```

Results :

abc

The program has unexpectedly finished.

Comment: Why are you declaring `project` as a pointer?  I suggest you get rid of it being a pointer and the code should work fine after changing `->` to `.`.

Comment: Totally unrelated to your problem, but [don't use leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter, such symbols are reserved in all scopes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: Why did you choose to declare your object as a pointer?

Answer (score 6):

That's because you have a pointer to a `Test` object, but it doesn't actually point anywhere. That leads to *undefined behavior* when you try to dereference the pointer.

Declare the object as an actual object, not a pointer:

```
Test project;
project.addName("abc");
```

Answer (score 1):

The pointer `project` is default-initialized and has indeterminate value, so dereferencing it has a big chance to cause abnromal termination of the program.

Try creating an object and assigning it before dereferencing like this:

```
#include "test.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Test* project = new Test;
    project->addName("abc");
    delete project;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No reason to use `new` here.

Comment: @crashmstr there *is* a need to use `new` here if the OP wishes to use `*project`. Otherwise, there is no reason to use `new` here if the OP changes what `project` is.

Comment: @johnbakers `*project` can be used without `new` like this: `Test hoge; Test *project = &hoge;`